# Remove all css styles using Javascript without removing the class

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to remove all CSS styles from a specific selector using Javascript, without removing the selector itself from the element?

The issue is that I'd like to add my own class to an element to handle the styling, but the element is created by a WordPress plugin and there are already classes on the element that overwrite mine. I cannot remove the original classes because they're also being used for Javascript.

Normally I'd give up and just stick `!important` on everything in my class, which I can still do if there's no other way, but the original classes have practically EVERYTHING defined, in multiple pseudo states, so I'd have to list out everything from `color:` to `border-bottom-right-radius:` with `!important` after it (including on `:focus` and `:hover` and everything) in order to overwrite all the original styles.

Basically I have this:

```
<button class="original-class-1 original-class-2">Button</button>

<style>
    .my-styles {
        color: #fafafa;
        background-color: #090909;
        border: 1px solid;
     }

    .original-class-1 {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        ...
        ...
        etc-with-everything-but-the-kitchen-sink: killme;
     }

     .original-class-2 {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        ...
        ...
        etc-with-even-more-stuff: why;
     }
</style>
```

and I want

```
<button class="original-class-1 original-class-2 my-styles">Button</button>

<style>
     .my-styles {
        color: #fafafa;
        background-color: #090909;
        border: 1px solid;
     }

     .original-class-1 {
     }

     .original-class-2 {
     }
</style>
```

At the moment I have something like this started:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.original-class-1');

for (const button of buttons ) {
    
    button.style.removeAllProperties(); // Does something like this exist?
    button.classList.add('my-styles');
    
}
```

To be clear, the original classes are adding styles from an **external** stylesheet, I've only put them in `<style>` tags above for illustration purposes.

Comment: `Does something like this exist?` no

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#how-to-create-a-child-theme

Comment: In a comment you noted that the plug-in styles are loaded later.  So the example css in the question is a bit misleading as it shows the custom styles loading after. Yet, it's a good question +1

Comment: True -- I've updated the original to clarify the cascade order I'm experiencing.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty not so eficient but i think something to do with what is being asked

Answer (score 1):

You could try experimenting with `all: revert`, or `all: initial` in CSS to reset styles from within the CSS rules of a custom class, before presenting actual rules for the class.

This snippet experiments with `revert` rather than `initial` (go with what works), using exaggerated styles to make changes obvious.

```css
.original-class-1 {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-width:7px;
    border-style: solid;
    /* plus more */
}
.original-class-1:hover {
   border-style: dashed;
}


.original-class-2 {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    /* plus more */
 
}

.my-styles, .my-styles:hover {
    all: revert;
    color: #fafafa;
    background-color: #090909;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button class="original-class-1 original-class-2">Button</button>
<button class="original-class-1 original-class-2 my-styles">Button2</button>
```

Pseudo element selectors didn't appear to respond to wild cards after the colon, say to specify rules for a  mythical "`.my-style:*`" selector, hence the explicit duplication of `.my-style` rules for the `.my-style:hover` selector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah I tried something like this but the plugin's stylesheet is loading after mine, so it would still overwrite the `all: revert`. If I can figure out how to get my styles inline though.... 

Comment: Regardless, I'm up voting because I find it interesting and think it could be helpful to others tying to solve a similar problem. +1

Comment: Thx. My next thought would be to load/append the custom stylesheet to the DOM in JavaScript, after an event such as `DOMContentLoaded` or similar fires. Unfortunately I'm not in a position to experiment with Wordpress, or know if it provides tricky alternatives.

Comment: Thanks @traktor -- it's giving me ideas anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The button elements in the example provided are styled using classes, not the element's "style" attribute. Since the button elements are styled using classes, you could try modifying the "class" attribute on the buttons.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.original-class-1');
  buttons.forEach(button => button.setAttribute('class', 'my-styles'));
}
```

```css
.original-class-1 {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: red;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.original-class-2 {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.my-styles {
  color: #fafafa;
  background-color: #090909;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<button class="original-class-1 original-class-2">Button</button>
```

As you can see here, the button element now has your .my-styles and does not have either of the original classes.

I'm unfamiliar with WordPress, this may be better approached through their tooling rather than manipulating your DOM in this way. Best of luck.

ref: [Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

---

EDIT:
If you want to get *really* hacky, you could always do something interesting like the following: ( I don't recommend you do this :-) )

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const targetClass = Object.values(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules).find((rule) => rule.selectorText == '.very-red');
    if (targetClass) {
        Object.values(targetClass.style).forEach((property) => targetClass.style.removeProperty(property));
    };
}
```

```css
.very-red {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="very-red">Very Not Red Button</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work.  The plug-in uses the existing class names as selectors.  If we remove them, as this code does, that breaks the plug-in.  And this is the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @glennpai but to clarify, I need to keep the original classes on the element (for the sake of Javascript) and only remove the styles attached to them. I was just hoping it would be easier than overwriting each CSS property individually.

Comment: @Shoelaced I see. I've updated my post with a method of emptying the class of all style properties. Again, I would advise against using this as it's somewhat costly depending on the class size and quite frankly sort of a silly brute force solution.

Answer (score 0):

**rewriting the stylesheet with js**

This is an unconventional approach that may have unforeseen effects but it uses javascript to re-write the relevant style sheet leaving empty rule sets for all selectors except those you have added (which must be identifiable by containing some constant label as part of their names, a `.my-` prefix in this example).

Style sheets are html elements like any other and can be accessed, and have their content manipulated, using javascript.

You will have to do some exploratory work by (reporting to console) each of the elements in the collection of style elements extracted in order to focus on the relevant sheet(s). Here, the collection relevant to the snippet tools style panel was easily found to be index [0], hence its use in the example.

If the steps are not clear, leave a comment and I'll explain each part's purpose.

```js
let styleSheetCollections = document.getElementsByTagName('style');

let stylesText = styleSheetCollections[0].innerHTML;
const stylesBlockArray = stylesText.split("{");
let keepNext = false;

for (let i=1; i<stylesBlockArray.length; i++) {

if (!keepNext) {
stylesBlockArray[i]=stylesBlockArray[i].slice(stylesBlockArray[i].indexOf("}")-1);
} // end if;

if (stylesBlockArray[i].indexOf("my-") > -1) {keepNext = true;} else {keepNext = false};

} // next block;

newInnerText = stylesBlockArray.join("{");

console.log(newInnerText);

// replace style sheet innerText
// styleSheetCollections[0].innerText = newInnerText;
```

```css
.original-class-1 {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        ...
        ...
        etc-with-everything-but-the-kitchen-sink: killme;
     }
     
     .my-p_style {
       font-size: 12px;
       border: 0;
     }

     .my-h1_style {
       font-size: 22px;
       background: yellow;
     }
     
     .original-class-2 {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        ...
        ...
        etc-with-even-more-stuff: why;
     }

     .my-styles {
        color: #fafafa;
        background-color: #090909;
        border: 1px solid;
     }
```

You would uncomment the assignment back to the stylesheet in the last line when done.

Answer (score 0):

Using Window.getComputedStyle() which returns a CSSStyleDeclaration Object, you could simply iterate the key/value pairs setting all to "initial".

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");


const element = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0];
const cssObj = window.getComputedStyle(element);




button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  for (x in cssObj) {
    cssObjProp = cssObj.item(x)
    let val = cssObj.getPropertyValue(cssObjProp);
    element.style.setProperty(val, "initial");
  }
});
```

```css
.myclass {
  font-size: xxx-large;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class=myclass>Testing one two.</p>
<button>Fire JavaScript</button>
```

Comment: This seems promising but it seems to just add `style="all: initial"` to the element, which overwrites my styles as well. Is there a way to just copy the styles from `.my-class` to the inline `style` attribute? If I could do that it might work...

Comment: Of course you can. You simply add your styles using JavaScript - using the same `setProperty` method on the element. First set all the styles to `initial` then add whatever styles you want.